# jsPDF && jsPDF AutoTable print spcial chars to PDF

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I'm creating PDF file from my HTML table usimg jsPDF AutoTable library, everythink works fine, PDF is always created but I have a problem with some special chars that are typical for my country. In my PDF file, strings that contain this characters are printed without them and what more, it looks like that every single char in this string is separated with space.

I cannot choose the way without this chars because they are included in names for example. The character I'm having problem with is for example c with hook -> č.

Below I'm giving you example where in first column on row number 1, 2, 3 and 4 is missing c with hook and characters are then separated with space.

[image: <a href="https://s3.postimg.io/cvm679ljn/table.png">table without c with hook</a><br>]

Don't you have any idea how to solve it?
I'm from Czech Republic if it helps (because of charset)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is probably related to that jspdf does not support utf-8. Follow updates regarding it in this [issue](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/12). The spacing issue is also mentioned there. Another good option for generating pdf files is [pdfmake](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake). It fully supports utf-8 characters.

Answer (score 5):

After released a version 1.4.0, the jsPDF finnaly support an encoding diacritics characters, but in a very strange way, imo.

1. Find the font which contains characters which you need. Let's say it will be a Calibri.
2. Go to `C:\Windows\Fonts\Calibri` and copy a `.ttf` font file to Desktop.
3. Go to [jsPDF FontConverter](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/fontconverter/fontconverter.html) and select copied font file. Click on the *Create* button.
4. You should get javascript file with content like this:

```js
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf"
var font = 'AAEAAAAWAQQAAB...==';
var callAddFont = function () {
  this.addFileToVFS('calibri-normal.ttf', font);
  this.addFont('calibri-normal.ttf', 'calibri', 'normal');
};
jsPDF.API.events.push(['addFonts', callAddFont]);
```

The second string in `this.addFont('calibri-normal.ttf', 'calibri', 'normal');` will be a name of your font. Remember it.

5. Add a downloaded javascript file to your project and import it: `import '../utils/calibri-normal';`
6. Go to place where you initialize a `jsPDF` object and set your font up:

```js
const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
doc.setFont("calibri");    // <-- place here your font name, which you remeber before
//...
doc.save('file001.pdf');
```

7. If you use jsPDF Autotable add new font to autotable settings too:

```js
doc.autoTable({
    head: [['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3']],
    body: someDataRows,
    styles: {
      font: 'calibri',    // <-- place name of your font here
      fontStyle: 'normal',
    },
    margin: { bottom: 60 }
});
```

8. Run your code - generated PDF should contain your font whith national charset.

Comment: This solution worked for me. 
I don't undersand why you use API. I think it not neccecary.

Comment: @maverabil: what do you mean by "use an API it's not necessary"? How do you convert a font file to a js without the FontConverter?

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks in advance. You saved me a lot.

Comment: Been struggling with that issue for hours and the 7th step is what finally worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> As 2023 Here is my solution:

```
    let font = null;
    await fetch('/fonts/poppins-v20-latin-ext_latin-regular.ttf')
      .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
      .then(fontData => {
        // Convert the ArrayBuffer to a base64-encoded string
        const fontDataArray = new Uint8Array(fontData);
        const base64FontData = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...fontDataArray));
        font = base64FontData;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        // Handle the error here
        console.log(err);
      });

    if (!font) return;
    // Add the font to vFS
    doc.addFileToVFS('poppins-v20-latin-ext_latin-regular.ttf', font);

    // Set unicode font
    doc.addFont('poppins-v20-latin-ext_latin-regular.ttf', 'Poppins', 'normal');
    doc.setFont('Poppins');

    doc.text(supplier, 10, 10);
    doc.text(date, 285, 10, {
      align: 'right'
    });
    // Use the autoTable function to create the table
    doc.autoTable({
      head: [headers.map(header => header.prompt)],
      body: tableData,
      startY: 20,
      theme: 'grid', // You can adjust the theme if needed
      styles: { fontSize: fontSize, font: 'Poppins' },
      headStyles: { fillColor: '#fbfbfb' },
      margin: { top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10 },
      didDrawPage: function (data) {
        // Add page numbers
        doc.text('Page ' + doc.internal.getNumberOfPages(), data.settings.margin.left, doc.internal.pageSize.height - 10);
      },
    });
```